# Cannot deploy ASP.NET Core 1.1 application due to bootstrap package in template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-deployment, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

I am using VS.2017 Community Edition and am starting to use the ASP.NET Core template to create websites. Previously I used the ASP.NET MVC5 (as in VS.2015).

Now that I have my website done I tried to deploy to my shared webhosting and after a while of adding files and uploading I got the following error on VS.2017.

**Web deployment task failed. Unable to perform the operation ("Create File") for the specified directory ("MyGet.ps1")**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(134,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (Unable to perform the operation ("Create File")  for the specified directory ("MyGet.ps1"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using.
```

I do not have any file named MyGet.ps1. However, I see that the DEFAULT VS.2017 web application template has a wwwroot\lib\bootstrap folder and therein I find the following files that I do not think should be part of the deploymet:

- bootstrap.less.nuspec
- bootstrap.nuspec
- MyGet.ps1

Why is it there? the template is not good? that I know only the bootstrap css files and JS should be part of deployment but not these!

Comment: Do you have bower set up to package your scripts and css as a pre- deployment task?

Comment: I have done nothing with Bower. I am using the standard vs.2017 template for asp.net core 1.1 web application.

Comment: You will still need to bundle your boostrap js and css if you are using bootstrap in your application so that it gets placed properly in your wwwroot folder structure.  Luckly, there's an extension for it.  Here's the ASP.NET Core docs on bundle/minify: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification